# Pentaho Kettle - Retrieving Data from different database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, kettle, pdi, pentaho-data-integration

I have a scenario where I'm fetching data from one database(postgres) and loading the data into a table in a different database(Redshift)

Is there anyway in Kettle to schedule this job ?

Its a simple `insert into redshift select * from postgres`

Comment: Table Input(connection to postgres) - > Table Output(connection to redshift). But adjust data types in between if there is need.

Comment: Get jdbc driver for amazon redshift and copy to $KETTLE_HOME/lib

Answer (score 1):

Using a Table Output step can be painfully slow as Redshift is optimized for bulk inserts, not row-by-row inserts. AFAIK, there are no steps/plugins in Kettle for bulk inserts into Redshift. What you can do, is to make a script in a Shell step that:

1. dumps data from Postgres to file
2. copies the data to S3: https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/11/30/loading-data-to-aws-s3-bucket-pentaho-data-integration/
3. inserts the data from S3 to Redshift: https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/12/11/loading-data-from-s3-to-redshift-pentaho-data-integration/